# Graph Api officeLocation

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to run:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=startsWith(officeLocation, 'MOD')`
and according to [Microsoft Docs user resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta):

> officeLocation    String
> Supports $filter (eq, ne, not, ge, le, in, startsWith, and eq on null values).

However, the response I am getting is:
`"error": {  "code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",   "message": "Unsupported or invalid query filter clause specified for property 'officeLocation' of resource 'User'.",`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add query parameter `$count=true` and header `ConsistencyLevel:eventual`.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=startsWith(officeLocation, 'MOD')&$count=true
```

[Advanced query capabilities on Azure AD directory objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http)

Comment: THANKS !!!
I was not even close to discover "ConsistencyLevel:eventual".
And thanks for the link.